# how to set image tag source from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, imagesource

How to set `image tag source` from reading the `key` from **AppSettings** section in `web.config` in html file.

I am using one html file, in which there is an image tag and I want to set image source from `web.config` file key.

The web.config key is:    `<add key="Image" value="Image.gif" />`

But i am not able to set the key on source.

I have tried this :

```
 <img src="<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Image"] %>" width="685" height="177" />
```

but is not reading the source from there.

Comment: What does the generated html look like, and what does the web.config entry look like?

Comment: Here is the web.config entry:  

<add key="Image" value="Image.gif" />

and here is the html for image tag:

<tr>    
      <td  colspan="2" ><img src="<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Image"] %>" width="685" height="177" /></td>        
 </tr>

Comment: is the image in the same location as the page? so is page.html in the same folder as image.gif?

Comment: is this a `HTML` or `aspx` file?

Comment: html file.It is an email template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like you're trying to generate a html file to be sent via email.  Your better off creating a html file with `place holders` for the information you want to **inject**.  Use a text reader to read the html from the file, and use regex or string.replace on the text replacing the `place holders` for the actual values.

> You will need to have a full URL to images.

e.g.

To read the HTML

```
var HTML = EmailTemplate.GetHTMLFromTemplate(path to template)

 public static string GetHTMLFromTemplate(string templatepath)
    {
        var TemplateBody = new StringBuilder();

        using (var Reader = new StreamReader(templatepath))
        {
            string Line;
            while ((Line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                TemplateBody.Append(Line);
            }
        }

        return TemplateBody.ToString();
    }
```

Then replace the parts of the html

```
String.Replace("[image placeholder]", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Image"]);
```

The Email Template class looks like this (this is very old code!!)

```
public class EmailTemplate
    {
        public string Body { get; private set; }

        public static EmailTemplate GetTemplate(string body, string url, string html)
        {
            var AmendedHTML = new StringBuilder(html);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[body]", body);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("../images", url + "images");

            var MyEmailTemplate = new EmailTemplate { Body = AmendedHTML.ToString() };

            return MyEmailTemplate;
        }

        public static EmailTemplate GetTemplate(string body, string title, string url, string year, string html)
        {
            var AmendedHTML = new StringBuilder(html);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[BODY]", body);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[HEADING]", title);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("../images", url + "images");
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[DATE]", year);
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[contactus.aspx]", url + "contactus/index.aspx");
            AmendedHTML.Replace("[unsubscribe.aspx]", url + "register/unsubscribe.aspx");

            var MyEmailTemplate = new EmailTemplate { Body = AmendedHTML.ToString() };

            return MyEmailTemplate;
        }

        public static string GetHTMLFromTemplate(string path)
        {
            var TemplateBody = new StringBuilder();

            using (var Reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string Line;
                while ((Line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    TemplateBody.Append(Line);
                }
            }

            return TemplateBody.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: `<img src="<%= System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Image"].ToString() %>" width="685" height="177" />`

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace a value in your .html email template.

You can do that by reading the file into memory, and replace a placeholder in your .html file.
Change the image tag to something like 
   `<img src="$$image$$" width="685" height="177" />`

Then in your code

```
string myString = "";
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Email/Product/<nameofthepage>.html"))) {
myString  = reader.ReadToEnd();   
}
myString = myString.Replace("$$image$$", ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Image"]);
```

then set the body property of your mail to `myString`

Comment: Stephen i just need to read this key from image source in html file.
Because i am doing other stuff in code behind.

Comment: In what folder is your image located?

Comment: ../Email/Product/Image.gif

Comment: then make the web.config key: "/Email/Product/Image.gif"

Comment: @user972569, unless the html file is also in Product?

Comment: @user972569, **view source** on the generated page, this is actually a `aspx` file, right?